# mysql cursor returned unknown values

Tags: mysql, cursor

I have following stored procedure that contains cursor.

But don't getting actual id field value and always show zero.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `comm_pay_intro`(IN `id` VARCHAR(20), IN `comm_type` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE i INTEGER;
 DECLARE userid varchar(20);
 DECLARE idx int(11);   
 DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT `id`, `user_id`
 FROM `temp_table` order by `id`;
set i=1;
OPEN curs1;
 read_loop: LOOP
FETCH curs1 INTO idx,userid;
insert into user_commission(rate_id, user_id) 
VALUES(1, idx);
END LOOP read_loop;
CLOSE curs1;
END
```

Comment: Avoid naming stored procedure parameters as the column names of your tables. (E.g.: `\`id\``)

Comment: @wchiquito thanks, its working now